# create heatmap of RPKM analysis

Tags: r, heatmap

I made an RPKM analysis of my data and I generated this result

```
head((RPKM_analysis))
                      a        b         c           d        e               f               g           h  
gene0         8.5099049 5.5732562   5.0730217  6.4162466  25.075330      19.163763           39.085439  21.368201
gene1         2.6056052 0.4082469   4.4356482  0.9731503   3.508077      41.594664            6.998682   2.742124
gene2         0.4727903 0.3678376   0.3397144  0.1221217   4.475466       2.936647            2.820639  17.592733
gene3         0.8390143 0.3199489   1.2082854  0.1856811  14.063714       4.129234            6.103459  33.116435
gene4         2.2246130 2.3719177   2.3547895  0.7456295  22.917552       7.871053            4.437163  76.596441
gene6       150.0407639 9.5132677 266.7380691 76.9122813 100.517840      61.350209          392.224464 158.130721
                       i        j          k                        l
gene0             34.667379 13.056078 90.2201082                8.3383381
gene1              4.642868  2.658317  0.5275397                0.6345467
gene2              1.864922  1.487531  8.1337453               24.3506878
gene3              2.594216  2.194451  6.2621722               49.8774268
gene4              4.922619  5.944980 41.6279899              119.1270556
gene6            582.504495 12.147723 74.0451493               11.8167852
```

It is possible to create a heatmap of this analysis? 
I used this script

```
heatmap_RPKM <- heatmap(as.matrix(RPKM_aalysis))
```

but the problem is that it doesn't show me rownames and colnames.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: You really, *really* should reconsider using RPKMs, [they’re inadequate](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/69/29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `gplots::heatmap.2`, it is more advanced comparing to `heatmap`:

```
library(gplots)
library(dendextend)
library(stringi)

dat   <- as.matrix(dat)
dst   <- as.dist(1 - cor(t(dat), method = "spearman"))
dend  <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dst))
title <- stringi::stri_unescape_unicode("I\\u2661 Heatmaps!")

heatmap.2(
  x          = dat,
  scale      = "row",
  dendrogram = "row",
  col        = heat.colors(25),
  key        = F,
  trace      = "none",
  Colv       = F,
  Rowv       = dend,
  srtCol     = 0,
  main       = title
)
```

[image]

Data:

```
dat <- read.table(
  text = "                      a        b         c           d        e               f               g           h  
gene0         8.5099049 5.5732562   5.0730217  6.4162466  25.075330      19.163763           39.085439  21.368201
gene1         2.6056052 0.4082469   4.4356482  0.9731503   3.508077      41.594664            6.998682   2.742124
gene2         0.4727903 0.3678376   0.3397144  0.1221217   4.475466       2.936647            2.820639  17.592733
gene3         0.8390143 0.3199489   1.2082854  0.1856811  14.063714       4.129234            6.103459  33.116435
gene4         2.2246130 2.3719177   2.3547895  0.7456295  22.917552       7.871053            4.437163  76.596441
gene6       150.0407639 9.5132677 266.7380691 76.9122813 100.517840      61.350209          392.224464 158.130721",
  stringsAsFactors = F, header = T
)
```

Comment: hey, thank you very much, but it reports me an error when I try to create dat using an object of 40000 and more genes.                                                       Error in text.default(x = xpos, y = par("usr")[3] - (1 + offsetCol) *  : 
  X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 11 could not be loaded
Inoltre: Warning message:
In image.default(1:nc, 1:nr, x, xlim = 0.5 + c(0, nc), ylim = 0.5 +  :
  semi-transparency is not supported on this device: reported only once per page
>

Comment: At which step it complains about that?

Comment: When I created the heatmap